# Multiclass SVM example

Tags: c#, machine-learning, svm, accord.net

I trying to understand first example code from this [Page](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_MulticlassSupportVectorMachine.htm)

```
double[][] inputs =
{
//               input         output
new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //  0 
new double[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //  0
new double[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //  0
new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //  0
new double[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //  0
new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //  1
new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //  1
new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
new double[] { 1, 0, 1, 1 }, //  2
new double[] { 1, 1, 0, 1 }, //  2
new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
};

int[] outputs = // those are the class labels
{
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
};

var teacher = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<Linear>()
{
// using LIBLINEAR's L2-loss SVC dual for each SVM
  Learner = (p) => new LinearDualCoordinateDescent()
  {
    Loss = Loss.L2
  }
};
teacher.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
var machine = teacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);
int[] predicted = machine.Decide(inputs);
double error = new ZeroOneLoss(outputs).Loss(predicted);
```

So far i think that i understand how this code works correct me if i am wrong.
It has some random data as `input` and some labeled classes as `output`. Through those `input` and `output` it uses the `MultiClass SVM` to label the `inputs` with the values of the `outputs`.

So far so good but i got confused when i try to put different data as `input`.
I tried to change the dataset with different combinations of 0 and 1

For example i changed the first line {0,1,1,0} to {1,1,1,1} and i am getting value of 1 for that line in the `predicted array` why is this happening ? Should not be the value for that line equal 0 in the `predicted array` ? Because the `output array` has the first 5 values as 0 ?

Comment: If you look at the inputs, '2' also has {1,1,1,1} as input. So, it should give '2' as probability of classifying {1,1,1,1} in category 2 will be more and not 1.

Comment: @Sam but why its 2? Should not be 0 ? Because the output array has the first 5 values as 0

Comment: It does not work on first input or last input, it creates a vector space of all the inputs and corresponding outputs for training.